# Excel Conditional Formatting based on the data on the right cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to set conditional formatting where the cell is equal to "3", then color red the cell on the left of it. Refer example below:

[image]

I have tried google like offset and stuff and it is not working for me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the below image (complete with column letters and row numbers) I selected B3:G6 and created a new [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) rule based on the following formula.

```
=AND(ISEVEN(COLUMN(B:B)), C3=3)
```

[image: cfr_offset]

Comment: Jeeped, that you for the solution. It works even if i put it =AND(ISEVEN(COLUMN(A:A)), B1=3). I really do not understand how this formula works but it works. If there is better explanation to that would be great :)